# Changing the app in Firebase console did not change the google-services.json file

Tags: flutter, firebase

I want to change the name and bundleId of my flutter app. I made the changes in the AndroidManifest file and the build.gradle file.

I added a new app in the firebase project but I still have com.example.deal_diligence in the package name in the google-services.json file.

The only change to the file was this line was added to the project_info section:
"firebase_url": "https://deal-diligence-5de73-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com",

I want to change the package name to com.kane.dealdiligence and this is the way it shows in the Firebase project settings but not in the .json file.

This is the Firebase settings:
[image]

How do I fix this?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Just download the file again and overwrite your current one:

[image: Firebase google-services.json tutorial]

And also make sure to add the fingerprints after you signed and built your app so Firebase can identify it.
Optionally, you may want to use the [flutterfire CLI](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/cli/) to manage your Firebase projects.

Comment: I downloaded the new .json file but like I said above, only one line changed.

Comment: This is weird because it shows the correct package name in the picture you provided, no clue why it doesn't update the file

Comment: Maybe you accidentally downloaded the json file of the old app?

Comment: No, I checked a couple times to make sure I didn't

Comment: Okay, this is kind of hard to debug from far. Maybe you could try to reload your browser, clear cache/delete website data, etc.

Comment: Do I need to remove the first app in Firebase?

Comment: If you don't need it anymore, I would delete it (since you created the new one with the new package ID). Just make sure to backup any important data before the deletion. If you want, we can move this discussion into a chat before this gets extented too much

Comment: I refreshed my browser and not the .json file has information for both apps. Is this bad or is it fine?

Comment: Do you mean that both apps are in the `client` section? I would remove the old one as you don't need it anymore, just to keep it clean. Could you let me know as soon as it works?

Comment: I removed the original app from firebase and downloaded the .json again. When I run the app the splash screen opens for about 5 seconds and then closes and then vscode says it is continuing to launch the app but nothing is happening.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256544/discussion-between-appsolves-and-losttexan).